# Is it possible to use the backup and/or restore function to create a new account in a new region?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm looking for options for failover in the case of a region outage that doesn't involve incurring the cost of having a hot second region and geo-redundancy. Is it possible to use the backup feature to manually create a new account in a new region and then upload the related documents?

I was looking at the restore feature and noticed these limitations:
**"The restored account is created in the same region where your source account exists. You can't restore an account into a region where the source account did not exist."**

I also saw this limitation which makes me wonder if backups work in case of region failure? Even with the geo-redundant backup storage option picked?:

**"The backups are not automatically geo-disaster resistant. You have to explicitly add another region to have resiliency for the account and the backup."**

Does this mean that the backups will also go down if geo-redundancy and multiple regions aren't set up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Backups can only be restored into the same region in which the account was created. Backups are not intended or able to provide resiliency to regional outages. And certainly cannot provide anything approaching 99.999% availability. Regional replication is the only means to provide resiliency to regional events for mission critical workloads.

Backup is by default is geo-dr into the pair for that region. These are only restored into the source region where the regional event impacted the storage for that region which prevents it from recovering normally.